# Can I use the word "Kerfuffle"in formal writing?

Tags: word-usage

I would like to find out if I can use the word *kerfuffle* in formal writing. English is not my first language and I am thinking of using the word *Kerfuffle* in my exam report.Is it too informal?

Here is the definition that I found on Google.

> Kerfuffle: a commotion or fuss, especially one caused by conflicting views.

Would it be too informal to say that *There is a common kerfuffle over whether or not people tend to like others who are similar to them*?

Comment: Google for 'kercuffle' and see if it appears in formal contexts (newspapers, books). Tell us what you find.

Comment: in my opinion, it is too informal.

Comment: Kerfuffle: an Argument : https://www.chronicle.com/blogs/linguafranca/2013/08/01/kerfuffle-an-argument/

Comment: Kerfuffle ... why the misspellings?  One comment with Kercuffle one answer with Kerkuffle

Comment: If I did, I wouldn't use it like that - *... common kerfuffle over ...* is *not* idiomatic.   A kerfuffle describes a resulting state of affairs, so you need to say what events produced it. It doesn't mean differing views exist in general, it means particular attempts to discuss an issue have degenerated into a nonproductive fuss. Kerfuffles are puny things. They aren't broad enough to describe issues with different camps.

Comment: Reminds me of 'furore' which Brits generally say like the identical Italian word meaning the same thing, and which Americans replace with 'furor', the original Latin word.

Comment: Please don’t use words you are not familiar with in another language. And don’t use this forum for purposes other than stated in the Tour.

Comment: Yes, but you must wear either a tie or a dress while writing it, to make it formal enough.

Comment: @GEdgar It was a tpyo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can You use the word “kerfuffle”in formal writing? YES.  [Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/kerfuffle)

> A kerfuffle is some kind of commotion, controversy, or fuss.

As in:

> You tell your little girl everything will be okay, or you tell your
>   tween how to handle a friend **kerfuffle**, or you commiserate with your
>   teen who’s complaining that his teacher hates him.  **Washington Post**
>   Aug 21, 2019

And from [WorldWideWords](http://www.worldwidewords.org/weirdwords/ww-ker1.htm):

> Though the White House spokesman Ari Fleischer used it in January
>   2002, it hasn’t been especially well-known there and a later
>   presidential usage caused something of a kerfuffle:
>
> President Bush used “kerfuffle” Monday during an appearance in Ohio,
>   and in so doing, he created a minor one himself. Some of the
>   president-watchers on duty in the press gallery had to stop in
>   mid-story and explain to America this novel new word from the man who
>   gave us “misunderestimated.” **The Lima News** (Ohio), 22 Mar. 2006.

Listed as informal in BrE, In AmE it is not always so designated.  AmE is also 'looser' than proper BrE, for better or worse. My sense is it can be used formally or informally, at least in AmE. Now 'bloody hell' ... that's another kerfuffle, and it not over the use of hell.

Comment: But I wouldn't use it in the context you suggest, to mean simply 'a difference of opinion'.

Answer (score 1):

The term is  certainly informal.

***[Kerfuffle](http://www.worldwidewords.org/weirdwords/ww-ker1.htm):***

> You will most commonly come across this wonderfully expressive word for a commotion or fuss in Britain and the British Commonwealth countries. It is rather informal, though it often appears in newspapers.

(worldwidewords.org)

Comment: But if it appears often in newspapers, doesn't that make it more likely on the formal side?

Comment: @Mitch - I clearly say it is “INFORMAL”